# Where clause for undefined columns

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I am writing a query but have ran into a problem.

```
select name, address, count(BL.card_no) 
from Book_Loans BL 
inner join Borrower B on BL.card_no = B.card_no 
where count(BL.card_no) > 1 group by name;
```

This does not work because I cannot use "where count(BL.card_no) > 1" because it says "Invalid use of group function." But I need to make sure that only counts of card numbers greater than 1 are shown, how else can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to place the predicate in the `HAVING` clause:

```
select name, address, count(BL.card_no) 
from Book_Loans BL 
inner join Borrower B on BL.card_no = B.card_no 
group by name
having count(BL.card_no) > 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

for aggregate function use having instead of where

```
select name, address, count(BL.card_no) 
from Book_Loans BL 
inner join Borrower B on BL.card_no = B.card_no 
group by name
having  count(BL.card_no) > 1;
```